# Nodejs - Return response while sql is running

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function that simply invokes another function that executes sql and returns a uuid. The idea is that - the sql is a long running task, and instead of making the user wait until the sql execution takes place, id like to send a uuid, with which they can make a subsequent request to fetch the results. Here is my code:

```
async getUUID() {
 await executeSql();
 let uuid = uuidv4();//being created using the library
 return uuid;
}

async executeSql() {
 //sql query stuff
}
```

However, I get the uuid only when the sql execution is complete. How can I make this more independent of the `executeSql` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
async getUUID() {
 executeSql();
 let uuid = uuidv4();//being created using the library
 return uuid;
}
```

`await` will wait for the promise return. If you do not want to wait, just  delete it. So It will run in asynchronous mode.

Comment: And you must notice that In this way if the sql do not execute successfully, it will still return the uuid.

Comment: thanks! I'm always torn between sync and async - how is adding await making it async and non blocking when It clearly is?

Comment: It's just the opposite, adding await makes async function sync, await, a(sync) wait, means wait the async function to return. It resolves that to wait for the return data from async function. If your async function have a return data, and you do not use await ,you will get null data because the async function do not finish yet.